# vb.net Get value from webbrowser to textbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox, getattribute

I'm trying to write a code to download a movie from some website and I'm stuck with trying to get this value to textbox, however rest of this code is already done so I think, that there will be no other problems. So this's code from a website:`

```
        <div style="width:750px;z-index: 0;background:#000;color:#FFF;text-align:center">
                <div class="embed">
                            <div style="height:429px;width:750px;z-index:0;position:relative;clear:both">
                <span id="206019b3744f78869b9bd120161c7b25"><object width="100%" height="100%" id="206019b3744f78869b9bd120161c7b25_api" name="206019b3744f78869b9bd120161c7b25_api" data="http://premium.iitv.info/static/player/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.15.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><param name="quality" value="high"><param name="bgcolor" value="#000000"><param name="flashvars" value="config={&quot;key&quot;:&quot;#$3f90d28e7547ada6c98&quot;,&quot;clip&quot;:{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;http://stream.streamo.tv/?scode=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&quot;,&quot;provider&quot;:&quot;lighttpd&quot;,&quot;scaling&quot;:&quot;fit&quot;,&quot;backgroundGradient&quot;:&quot;none&quot;,&quot;autoPlay&quot;:false,&quot;autoBuffering&quot;:false},&quot;canvas&quot;:{&quot;backgroundColor&quot;:&quot;#000&quot;,&quot;backgroundGradient&quot;:&quot;none&quot;},&quot;plugins&quot;:{&quot;lighttpd&quot;:{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;flowplayer.pseudostreaming-3.2.11.swf&quot;,&quot;queryString&quot;:&quot;%3Fstart%3D%24%7Bstart%7D&quot;},&quot;controls&quot;:{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;flowplayer.controls-3.2.14.swf&quot;,&quot;autoHide&quot;:&quot;always&quot;}},&quot;playerId&quot;:&quot;206019b3744f78869b9bd120161c7b25&quot;,&quot;playlist&quot;:[{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;http://stream.streamo.tv/?scode=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&quot;,&quot;provider&quot;:&quot;lighttpd&quot;,&quot;scaling&quot;:&quot;fit&quot;,&quot;backgroundGradient&quot;:&quot;none&quot;,&quot;autoPlay&quot;:false,&quot;autoBuffering&quot;:false}]}"></object></span>`
```

and I would like to get this:

```
<param name="flashvars" value="config={&quot;key&quot;:&quot;#$3f90d28e7547ada6c98&quot;,&quot;clip&quot;:{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;http://stream.streamo.tv/?scode=w0GCOWxpkyGA4MJoRu2ETWHHZI3ZEIHojZHZPERJI9PIO90YyE0XMEQF3qUBQA1nkERocWaLaWxEipGn4cHGuuRIH9FnaM3p3fzZHq0oxyHBOERo5AGJvSKoUuHok80X4IwoIq3FhuJBe1RI5AJp30zE4MKpYS0DRAGoKczo5VmIPkTMSIzovWRpvOmE1pwM3gTo65JrlDILSyzFGMHIGWyG1c2G3pzJcEKIX9TJ0NQrSWGp1jxF4IUqeg2nepaqL5RG2cRr55zAaIKIYIKIEWwpCWJHnqmLzA1Z19RqeZmZJcUMeymoeDJGQg2pvkJq3NaZ1x2LzqyIVWyH5f2pLgTMCyIHMW1XcSzDREIGlqyDd50LIyIpbyHL1HyIUImEwuTrGAxnbuxD192Y61HLnSyHL9HBxyUokkHJj92LUSyEFMxAi1xnP1TqGWRrnSUB0N3H1W2ZTATGZyJBcWTrvIxq2LKnf9TnjSJnjtKoUy1E6WaoiZTIT52HjWSZh9RFxMJJaAmEcSKF&quot;,&quot;provider&quot;:&quot;lighttpd&quot;,&quot;scaling&quot;:&quot;fit&quot;,&quot;backgroundGradient&quot;:&quot;none&quot;,&quot;autoPlay&quot;:false,&quot;autoBuffering&quot;:false},&quot;canvas&quot;:{&quot;backgroundColor&quot;:&quot;#000&quot;,&quot;backgroundGradient&quot;:&quot;none&quot;},&quot;plugins&quot;:{&quot;lighttpd&quot;:{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;flowplayer.pseudostreaming-3.2.11.swf&quot;,&quot;queryString&quot;:&quot;%3Fstart%3D%24%7Bstart%7D&quot;},&quot;controls&quot;:{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;flowplayer.controls-3.2.14.swf&quot;,&quot;autoHide&quot;:&quot;always&quot;}},&quot;playerId&quot;:&quot;206019b3744f78869b9bd120161c7b25&quot;,&quot;playlist&quot;:[{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;http://stream.streamo.tv/?scode=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&quot;,&quot;provider&quot;:&quot;lighttpd&quot;,&quot;scaling&quot;:&quot;fit&quot;,&quot;backgroundGradient&quot;:&quot;none&quot;,&quot;autoPlay&quot;:false,&quot;autoBuffering&quot;:false}]}">
```

or it may be full 4 line if this's necessery.

I've been searching a solution for last 5 hours and I can't find anything usefull...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty way to do this would be to:

1) Download the HTML contents of the web page into a string using the following code:

```
Dim htmlContent As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(<Enter URL Here>)
```

2) ... and then search the string for your code.  One way to do this would be to first locate at which position in the HTML the string "http://stream.streamo.tv/?scode=" is located ...

```
Dim codeLocation As Integer = htmlContent.IndexOf("http://stream.streamo.tv/?scode=")
```

And then go through each subsequent character, building the code character by character, until you reach a termination character (like "&").

I am assuming that this code only appears once on the page.  If not, you will need to find a way to cycle through each instance (not difficult but not covered here).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would work, however it's a dynammic part of html code so there is no link in page source and you can only find it if you select "inspect element" function...

I was trying to do something like this, but I can't find working solution...:

```
For Each h As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("value")
If Not Object.ReferenceEquals(h.GetAttribute("name"), Nothing) AndAlso h.GetAttribute("name").Equals("flashvars") Then
Tbox1.Text = h.InnerText
Exit For
End If
Next
```

If I do this:

```
(...).SetAttribute("Value", TextBox4.Text)
```

Then I can set data here:

```
<param name="flashvars" value="here"></param>
```

But I don't known how to reverse this and get this to textbox:

```
?textbox1..AppendText(WebBrowser1.Document.GetAttribute("value")?
```

Comment: Can you include a link to a sample page so we could look at it?

Comment: I'm afraid, that I can't give you link, becouse you would need a premium account, however I can give you this website in html file here: http://speedy.sh/tYe93/CSI-Kryminalne-zagadki-Miami-Habeas-Corpse-s10e19.html

Comment: This one should work: http://speedy.sh/uEC8F/CSI-Kryminalne-zagadki-Miami-Habeas-Corpse-s10e19.rar

Comment: And now I've just realised, that This, what I send to you was after i click to load player, but if I don't click then page looks like this... :http://speedy.sh/Cn9Vg/CSI-Kryminalne-zagadki-Miami-Habeas-Corpse-s10e191.rar

Comment: And this is how html code looks like before click:<div id="player">
                <div id="player_2" hash="wZlV90mMU9zowqUo2gFAAymYjS2M3yKJeuaEAcKFwOUBD1HHPISrEIUMaEyI2y3ITS3A6AxIPq2AJS2DZAmHjEGIPymDHAIZES2D5ZGoFuTniI2oHOGLaWGoZSaDmcypwSKp"></div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>      and after click: <div id="player_2" hash="wZlV90GDL92DxuUF4q3LYSQrJAmq1N3H0pGZuWUFiHmHPcRr3WmE4LyqZMaFQqSAPcaqaAwEiLxpDuIMAESqYcREaSapRE0n0tQqmuwAOE0D6EHLnMzqfyarLWxpCMTrxMxq"></div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

Comment: so probably while I was saving the page, there saved also code generated by java

Comment: So your idea was good, except for the detail that to download this page, you must be logged in the browser session, so it would be necessary to download it using webbrowser1, which brings me to the starting point, because I have no idea how to do it...

Answer (score 0):

ChicagoMike thank you for giving me the idea to download the source and search them, but the problem was how to run javascript earlier, but I managed to solve this problem this way:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.Window.DomWindow.execscript("text/JavaScript")

    Dim MSDNpage2 As String = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml

    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("e:\msdn2.txt", MSDNpage2, True)

    RichTextBox6.Text = MSDNpage2
```